# bootstrap glyphicon in input filed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I place a glyphicon in an input field?

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success and icon</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It is located below the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the label next to the input (rather than above) you can use a `form-horizontal`. If you arrange your html like this then the icon will appear inside the input :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/rXcXvNn1ZD